# VS Code can't see css files in intellisense

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code

I'm building a react app but when I import a `.css` file, the vscode doesn't show the file in the intellisense.

[image]

I'm not sure if this is a problem with vs code or something in my webpack config.

If you think that the webpack config file is important for this problem, I can post it on the question.

## Edit:

When I add a `.js` or `.jsx` file, it appears normally, but `.css` files don't

[image]

I don't use any extensions for the paths.

Answer (score 17):

VS Code doesn't support path completion for all file types. But you should get this going with the [Path Autocomplete extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ionutvmi.path-autocomplete).

Comment: This extension also works great for suggesting path completion.
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=christian-kohler.path-intellisense

Comment: @AnkushChauhan "Path Intellisense" does not show `.css` file in suggestions when importing in js file, how to make it work ?

Comment: path autocomplete doesn't work well with jsconfig.json...

Comment: I got path autocompletion, but goto definition/file doesn't work for  me? Anyone fixed this?

Comment: Also con you explain why `className` is not autocompleting, with a solution?

Answer (score 3):

Use **Path Intellisense** Extension in vs code

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=christian-kohler.path-intellisense

Answer (score 2):

christian-kohler.path-intellisense do works great for suggesting path completion with .css

Just disable the built-in path auto-complete function in settings

```
{ "typescript.suggest.paths": false }
{ "javascript.suggest.paths": false }
```