# VScode: How to autocomple json/scss/image file paths from shortcut paths specified in jsconfig shortcuts

Tags: webpack, visual-studio-code, intellisense, compiler-options, vscode-jsconfig

When doing imports, intellisense will suggest autocompletion names when I am trying to import a React `.jsx` component. Nothing will be suggested when I am trying to import `json` or `scss` files though.

I have a set of aliases that I set up in my `webpack.config.js`

```js
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.css', '.js', '.jsx'],
    alias: {
      'src': path.resolve(__dirname + '/src'),
      'data': path.resolve(__dirname + '/src/data'),
      'assets': path.resolve(__dirname + '/src/assets'),
      'images': path.resolve(__dirname + '/src/assets/images'),
      'styles': path.resolve(__dirname + '/src/assets/styles'),
      'components': path.resolve(__dirname + '/src/components'),
      'types': path.resolve(__dirname + '/src/types'),
      'functions': path.resolve(__dirname + '/src/functions'),
      'pages': path.resolve(__dirname + '/src/pages')
    }
  },
```

And because I want intellisense to autocomplete these paths, I created a jsconfig.json

```js
    {
        "compilerOptions": {
          "jsx": "react",
          "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
          "target": "es6",
          "baseUrl": "./",
          "paths": {
            "src": ["./src"],
            "src/*": ["./src/*"],
            "data": ["./src/data"],
            "data/*": ["./src/data/*"],
            "assets": ["./src/assets"],
            "assets/*": ["./src/assets/*"],
            "images": ["./src/assets/images"],
            "images/*": ["./src/assets/images/*"],
            "styles": ["./src/assets/styles"],
            "styles/*": ["./src/assets/styles/*"],
            "components": ["./src/components"],
            "components/*": ["./src/components/*"],
            "types": ["./src/types"],
            "types/*": ["./src/types/*"],
            "functions": ["./src/functions"],
            "functions/*": ["./src/functions/*"],
            "pages": ["./src/pages"],
            "pages/*": ["./src/pages/*"],
          }
        },
        "exclude": ["node_modules"],
        "checkJs": "true"
      }
```

---

I have [path intellisense](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=christian-kohler.path-intellisense) installed

I also have my `keybindings.json` set up to be

```
[
    { "key": ".", "command": "" }
]
```

I also added `"typescript.suggest.paths": false` to my `.vscode/setting.json` as suggested in the path intellisense documentation although I am **not using typescript**. This is just a javascript project.

Comment: Look for the comments of the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56241357/vs-code-cant-see-css-files-in-intellisense

Comment: what extensions do you have? I'm not certain but I think you might need an scss extension.

Comment: @Nailuj29 Do you know which one?

Comment: @AdamP. I might have path autocomplete, it's on my work computer, form the comments it doesn't look like it works anyway. The main thing I want is intellisense for json, so that I can have autocompletion when I'm trying to use a variable from a json file

Comment: @Sam Sorry, I think I misunderstood your question.  I don't think VS Code supports using variables in JSON files with Intellisense. You could just load the JSON file in and use `JSON.parse` to access it.

Comment: @Nailuj29 It does if I use absolute paths, or relative paths, but not when I'm using shortcuts

Comment: @Sam what is you vscode version and are you using it in windows

Comment: @Chandan 1.5.1.1 and yes I'm using Windows

Comment: @Sam did you checked without `jsonconfig.json` if it give suggestion for scss, json, css

Comment: It gives suggestions for none of the shortcuts without the jsconfig. With the jsconfig, at least the jsx and js files are suggested. Using relative paths (not using the shortcuts) results in autocompleted files

Comment: @Sam did you tried with [path-intellisense.mappings](https://github.com/ChristianKohler/PathIntellisense#mappings)

Comment: @Chandan I don't think so

Comment: @Chandan I added `"path-intellisense.mappings": {
    "assets": "${workspaceRoot}/src/assets",
    "styles": "${workspaceRoot}/src/assets/styles"
  },` to my `jsconfig.json` and it didn't do anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to add

```
    "compilerOptions": {
        "resolveJsonModule": true,
```

to my jsconfig.json for json

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't see any .scss or .css files in JSX, TSX, or TS (JS was fine) - I use the Path Intellisense extension by Kohler.

Fixed it by adding this to my vscode settings.json:

```
"javascript.suggest.paths": false,
"typescript.suggest.paths": false
```